# How do I run a Windows 10 metro app from a custom media key?

Tags: windows-10, hotkeys

I have a generic media keyboard and I would like run a modern (Metro) Windows 10 application from a custom media key.

How do I this without software for a specific keyboard brand?

Answer (score 0):

- Drag the Metro app from the Start Menu to the desktop to create a shortcut.
- Save and rename the shortcut to a long-term suitable location.
- Record the full path to the shortcut. e.g `C:\Stuff\AppShortcut.lnk`
- Open the Windows Registry Editor* (`regedit`)
- Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AppKey`
- Find the desired application command event; you may need to create the one you want. Here's a [list of possible command numbers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646275%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (not all may be supported by your media keyboard).
- Change the *ShellExecute* value to point to the location of your application shortcut. You may need to replace an existing non-*ShellExecute* command (e.g. *Association*).
- Try out your re-configured media key.

<sub>* Create a system restore point or backup the registry if this is new territory.</sub>